# Entity Framework 6 : ignore property on basetype for all derived types

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, odata

I need to ignore the property `State` on `abstract class BaseEntity`, but I can't get this to work without using the `[NotMappedAttribute]`, but if I use the attribute the property also gets ignored in the OData API.

I have set up a github project to test this here:
https://github.com/nurf3d/EntityFrameworkDerivedTypesIgnoreProperiesTest/tree/master

Inheritance chain:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Rowversion { get; set; }

    public State State { get; set; }
}

[Table("Events")]
public abstract class Event : BaseEntity
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedEvent1 : Event
{
    public bool IsDerivedEvent1 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedEvent2 : Event
{
    public bool IsDerivedEvent2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Attributes**:

When using `[NotMappedAttribute]`, the `State` propery gets ignored for all types correctly and the migration runs fine, but this also removes the property from the OData API, which we don't want.

Since we need the `State` property within the OData API, we are not using the `[NotMappedAttribute]`, but the fluent configuration.

Fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Types<BaseEntity>().Configure(clazz => clazz.Ignore(prop => prop.State));

add-migration Initial -Force
```

Results in this error:

> You cannot use Ignore method on the property 'State' on type 'EntityFrameworkIgnoreProperty.Models.DerivedEvent1' because this type inherits from the type 'EntityFrameworkIgnoreProperty.Models.BaseEntity' where this property is mapped. To exclude this property from your model, use NotMappedAttribute or Ignore method on the base type.

I need to get this to work with the Fluent api and I need to do this for all derived types of `BaseEntity` at once.

In my real project I have 100+ entities, I can't do this by hand for every single entity, especially considering future development.

Comment: Is `BaseEntity` class mapped as entity (i.e. participating in EF inheritance)?

Comment: No `BaseEntity` is not mapped as a seperate entity. In this example only Event should be mapped as an entity with TPH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the fact that `Types` method body is called for each class inheriting `BaseEntity` directly or indirectly, which is causing issues with EF inheritance.

What you could do is to use a filter to apply the configuration only for direct derived types like this:

```
modelBuilder.Types<BaseEntity>()
    .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(BaseEntity))
    .Configure(clazz => clazz.Ignore(prop => prop.State));
```

Comment: Thank you that did the trick! I know I already had this before, but I cant remember the issue I had with it.. Anyway...this seems to solve all my problems!